# JavaME: make emulator run a different JRE

Tags: java-me, java-wireless-toolkit

My first steps with JavaME, currently using [Sun's WTK 3.0](http://java.sun.com/products/sjwtoolkit/overview.html)

I understand a JavaME device runs its own Runtime Environment, and that's a 1.3 JRE.

Is it possible to make the emulator run the JavaSE JDK 6 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JavaME runtime is not JRE 1.3

It is a Microedition runtime BASED on what java standard edition was back around the time JRE 1.3 was released.

You can use JavaSE JDK 6 to develop a JavaME runtime (that's pretty much what microemulator is) but the application management and lifecycle of a MIDlet doesnt match that of a JavaSE application.

You cannot use the latest specification of the JavaSE language (genericity... ) when writing MIDlets.